# SmartEnumerable and Regex.Matches

Tags: c#, regex, ienumerable

I wanted to use Jon Skeet's [SmartEnumerable](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/smartenumerable.html) to loop over a `Regex.Matches` but it does not work.

```
foreach (var entry in Regex.Matches("one :two", @"(?<!\w):(\w+)").AsSmartEnumerable())
```

Can somebody please explain me why? And suggest a solution to make it work. Thanks.

The error is:

```
'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition
for 'AsSmartEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsSmartEnumerable' accepting
a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I think you forgot to insert the `.AsSmartEnumerable()` call in your sample code. The reason *that* won't compile is because the extension-method only works on `IEnumerable<T>`, not on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface.

---

It's not that you can't enumerate the matches that way; it's just that the type of `entry` will be inferred as `object` since the [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) class does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface, only the `IEnumerable` interface.

If you want to stick with implicit typing, you will have to produce an `IEnumerable<T>` to help the compiler out:

```
foreach (var entry in Regex.Matches("one :two", @"(?<!\w):(\w+)").Cast<Match>())
{ 
   ...
}
```

or, the nicer way with explicit-typing (the compiler inserts a cast for you):

```
foreach (Match entry in Regex.Matches("one :two", @"(?<!\w):(\w+)"))
{ 
   ...
}
```

The easiest way to produce a smart-enumerable is with the provided extension-method:

```
var smartEnumerable = Regex.Matches("one :two", @"(?<!\w):(\w+)")
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .AsSmartEnumerable();

foreach(var smartEntry in smartEnumerable)
{
   ...
}
```

This will require a `using MiscUtil.Collections.Extensions;` directive in your source file.

Comment: The casting does not work for me (I am using .NET 4): `'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You need a `using System.Linq` directive at the top of your file.